# Setting 2 trigonometric functions equal to each other

Tags: trigonometry

> $$y = \frac{\sec^2(x)}{2} \;\;\;\; \operatorname{and} \;\;\;\; y = 2\cos^2(x).$$

I have to set these equal to each other to find the value of $x$ but I haven't done one of these in a long time so I do not know how to find $x$ for these functions.

Answer (score 2):

Using the definition of secant $$\sec x = \frac 1 {\cos x}$$ this is equivalent to having

$$\frac{1}{2 \cos^2 x} = 2 \cos^2 x$$

Upon rearrangement, this leads to

$$\cos^4 x = \frac 1 4$$

It follows that $\cos x = \pm \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}$; I'll leave it to you to finish the details of finding $x$.

Comment: I don't understand how you got cos^4x = 1/4. How did you dive 2cos^2x by the fraction or the fraction by the other number.

Comment: @Tim Multiply both sides by $\cos^2 x$, and divide both sides by $2$.